# Unable to get the DspStatus Field in the Task document properties

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am using Interop.Domino.dll API to read the NSF file and able to read the properties of the Task Document.

```
When i view the Task Document properties in the Lotus Notes, i am able to view the Status Field, Importance Field and few others, but when i programatically dump all the Field Names and their values i am unable to get few of them as mentioned above.

So, how to get all the Field Names and their values as i iterate through all the document properties. Is this the problem of IBM Lotus Notes Application or the Domino API ?

Here is my sample code to iterate the TODO document properties :
```

object[] TaskItems = docTodoDoc.Items as object[];

foreach (NotesItem objItem in TaskItems)
   {
      m_objLogFile.Debug(objItem.Name + " -> ");

```
  m_objLogFile.Debug("Values :: " + ((object[])docTodoDoc.GetItemValue(objItem.Name))[0] as String);
```

}

Please help me out to over come this issue as i need to access the status value of the TODO Item from the NSF file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the DspStatus field type is "Computed for display" and these types of fields are not actually saved with the document they are as the name implies computed for display only.  If you have access to verify the lotus notes form design you can verify the formula for that field and probably get the field where it's computing it's valued from.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That field is almost certainly Status, which will contain a textified integer value. @Preeti Singh: the out-of-the-box Notes applications (Mail, Discussion, etc.) are all multilingual. The code is the same for all languages; the only thing that changes is the labels you see in the UI and the display value of fields that drive the system. The Status field is what matters, and it will contain a value like "1" or "2". The DispStatus field just translates that value into something the user can understand.